# Webtechnick CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin permissions not working

Tags: facebook, cakephp, plugins

I'm using the Webtechnick CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin in order to log my users into my CakePHP application, I need to get their user_relationship, user_relationship_details, user_religion_politics and email.

Im using something kike this to invoke the login button

```
echo $this->Facebook->login(array('perms' => 'email,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_relationship_details', 'redirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'facebook'), 'label' => __('<span class="icon-facebook-sign"></span> Login with facebook',true),'id' => 'facebook_btn' ));
```

And also in facebook on "App details" in the "Configure App Center Permissions" section I'm adding the permissions too, but its not working, when a user login into the app facebook is still requesting the default perms (public profile, friends list and email).

---

I solved it, It seems that I was missing $options parameter on my init function.
So I changed the call in my default.ctp file

from

```
$this->Facebook->init();
```

to

```
$this->Facebook->init(array('perms' => 'email,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_relationship_details'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, It seems that I was missing $options parameter on my init function.
So I changed the call in my default.ctp file

from

```
$this->Facebook->init();
```

to

```
$this->Facebook->init(array('perms' => 'email,user_religion_politics,user_relationships,user_relationship_details'));
```